# Set algebra theorem proving, is this correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I was told to prove that

> If x and y are subsets of *U* (*U* denotes a nonempty universal set), then x $\cap$ y = x iff x $\cup$ y = y

Here is my proof:

> x $\cup$ *U* = *U*  (universal set property)
> x $\cup$ (y $\cup$ y$^{'}$) = *U* (complement)
> (x $\cup$ y) $\cup$ y$^{'}$ = *U* (associative property) 
>
> x $\cap$ y =  x 
> (x $\cap$ y) $\cap$  y$^{'}$ = x $\cap$ y$^{'}$ (not sure if this is allowed)
> x $\cap$ $\varnothing$ = x $\cap$ y$^{'}$ (associative property and complement)
> x $\cap$ y$^{'}$ = $\varnothing$ (annihilator) 
> (x $\cap$ y$^{'}$) $\cup$ $\varnothing$ = $\varnothing$ (identity) 
> (x $\cap$ y$^{'}$) $\cup$ (y $\cap$ y$^{'}$) = $\varnothing$ (complement) 
> (x $\cup$ y) $\cap$ y$^{'}$ = $\varnothing$ (distributive)
> since (x $\cup$ y) $\cup$ y$^{'}$ = *U* and (x $\cup$ y) $\cap$ y$^{'}$ = $\varnothing$, (x $\cup$ y) must be the unique complement of y$^{'}$, which would be y 
> proof on the other way will follow the same logic by the duality of set algebra 
> Q.E.D

Is the proof valid?

Comment: I'm still reading through your answer, but I feel that there's a simpler and more satisfying approach we can take by using the definitions of the union and intersection in a more elementary way.

Comment: That said, I do think your approach is valid, the one step you seem worried about does work and could be proven rather quickly and included as a lemma if you're really worried about it. And in fairness I do like the proof, I just think it's a touch inappropriate for the problem considering the proofs for any of the rules you use aren't much less complicated than an elementary proof of the original statement, it feels a bit like kicking the can down the road if that makes sense. (but I'm being a bit of a stickler)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I do recognize that my method is rather forced, but I am glad that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct, there is another simpler way (although I like yours better):

(forward direction) We have $X\cap Y=X$, and wish to show $X\cup Y=Y$. Let $z\in X\cup Y$, then $z\in X$ or $z\in Y$. But if $z\in X$, then $z\in X\cap Y$ so $z\in Y$. Hence, $X\cup Y\subseteq Y$. We know, $Y\subseteq X\cup Y$ so it follows that $X\cup Y=Y$.

The backward direction follows a similar argument.

---

Other than that, you can see that both $X\cap Y=X$ and $X\cup Y=Y$ are equivalent to $X\subseteq Y$. Your definition might differ. The defintion I have used and seen is if $x\in X\implies x\in Y$, then $X\subseteq Y$.

Now, if $X\cap Y=X$, then
$$x\in X\implies x\in X\cap Y\implies x\in Y$$
and if $X\subseteq Y$, then
$$x\in X\implies x\in Y \implies x\in X\cap Y$$
and $x\in X\cap Y\implies x\in X$, so $X\cap Y=X$ and overall we have$$X\subseteq Y\iff X\cap Y=X$$
You can show the other equivalence similarly.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for noting the much simpler and also more intuitive proof. The reason for my lengthy proof is due to the question suggesting only using set algebra properties to proof it, so I was hesitant to use elements in my proof. It definitely took me some time, but I am glad it worked.

Comment: @Breathe111 I was unaware of this suggestion, in that case I would retract my complaint regarding the heavy-duty nature of your proof.

Comment: @Breathe111: Your proof is definitely interesting. I will look if I can find some other way of writing these arguments using set algebra and update here.